# php switch case: if we have 30 options, do we have to create 30 if statements or is there an easier way?

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu, switch-statement

I found this code below and it works perfect for what I want BUT I have over 30 options is there something else I can do to shorten the code?

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="?">
    <select name="dropdown">
    <option value="Jehzeel1">Jehzeel1</option>
    <option value="Jehzeel2">Jehzeel2</option>
    <option value="Jehzeel3">Jehzeel3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>



    <?php
    switch ($_POST['dropdown'])  { 

        case "Jehzeel1":
         echo "Jehzeel likes apples";
        break;

        case "Jehzeel2":
         echo "Jehzeel likes bananas";
        break;

        case "Jehzeel3":
         echo "Jehzeel likes oranges";
        break;

    ?>
```

Comment: In this situation, or in general?

Comment: Or dont have a switch at all, store the values in your/a database/array, generally switches are for logic not data selection.

Comment: the echo would be css <style> </style> it will override the core stylesheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to create a mapping array:

```
$map = array(
    'Jehzeel2' => 'Jehzeel likes bananas';
    'Jehzeel3' => 'Jehzeel likes oranges';
);

echo $map[$_POST['dropdown']];
```

Although you may want to think twice about your code structure, this looks like a bad practice.

**Short way:**

```
<?php
$fruits = array('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas');
?>
<form method="post">
    <select name="dropdown">
    <?php foreach ($fruits as $fruit) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fruit ?>"><?php echo $fruit ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if (in_array($_POST['dropdown'], $fruits)) {
    echo 'Jehzeel likes ' . $_POST['dropdown'];
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

You can use urls by slightly changing the array and the if statement:

```
$urls = array('url1' => 'http://www.facebook.com/', 'url2' => 'http://www.google.com/', 'url3' => 'http://www.yahoo.com/');

if (isset($urls[$_POST['dropdown']])) {
    echo 'URL: ' . $urls[$_POST['dropdown']];
}
```

Comment: I'd DRY that and just store the fruit name in the array.

Comment: @Wooble That would be the better way of doing it but he didn't ask for that. Well not specifically at least...

Comment: "something else I can do to shorten the code" seems to cover... shortening the code.

Comment: whichever way is effective and is the best

Comment: @user1757516 I edited my answer with a shorter way of your code. One of the many possibilities

Comment: can we change the fruit to urls?

Comment: @user1757516 I have edited my answer to give you an idea of how that could work.

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing the values of your options to something like:

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="apples">Jehzeel1</option>
    <option value="bananas">Jehzeel2</option>
    <option value="oranges">Jehzeel3</option>
</select>
```

Then simply in your php code:

```
$valid_fruits = array("apples", "bananas", "oranges");

$fruit = $_POST['dropdown'];
if(in_array($fruit,$valid_fruit))
    echo "Jehzeel likes $fruit"
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: A valid approach; however, this way you can't validate the user input.  I could change the HTML to `Strawberries` and inject that value into the app. Not necessarily a problem, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array with the values as the key, and the text as the value:

```
 // array of key/value pairs
 $text = array(
     "Jehzeel1" => "apples",
     "Jehzeel2" => "bananas",
     "Jehzeel3" => "oranges",
 );
 // create your key from the post value, make sure it is actually set
 $key = isset($_POST['dropdown']))? $_POST['dropdown'] : "";
 // echo the value based on the key, if the key exists
 $value = (array_key_exists($key, $text))? $text[$key] : "nothing";
 // assuming all the text starts with "Jehzeel likes" you can sprintf the value
 echo sprintf("Jehzeel likes %s.", $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create an array with your options**:

```
$DropdownLabels = array (
    'dropdown1' => 'Dropdown1 Long Label',
    'dropdown2' => 'Dropdown2 Long Label',
    // ...,
);
```

And then use `$DropdownLabels[$_POST['dropdown']]` and test if it exists with `array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown'], $DropdownLabels)`.